# Finding the last two digits of a large exponent

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find the last two digits of 37<sup>45</sup>

I know I need to solve 37<sup>45</sup> = x(mod 100), but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I know it has something to do with Euler's

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What is $\phi(100)$?

Comment: Do you know the Euler's theorem? Do you see $a=37,n=100$?
$$
a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod n)
$$
 Do you know how to find $\varphi(100)=40$ ? Do you know that:
$$
a^{x+ y}=a^{x}\cdot a^{y}
$$
This is all you need..
$$
37^{45}=37^{40}37^5\equiv1\cdot37^5\pmod{100}
$$
Where $37^5=69343957$ so the last two digits are $57$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last Two Digits Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759810/last-two-digits-problem)

Comment: @Vepir This makes the most sense to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$100=4\cdot 25$$

$$37^{45}\equiv 1 \pmod 4$$

$$37^{45}\equiv 12^{45} \pmod {25}$$

$$12^{45}\equiv (6)^{22} \cdot 12 \equiv 11^{11}\cdot 12 \equiv (-4)^5\cdot 11\cdot 12 \equiv -1024\cdot 11\cdot 12 \pmod {25}$$

Finally we get

$$37^{45}\equiv 7 \pmod {25}$$

Now we can quickly apply the chinese remainder theorem to solve the linear congruences

$$x\equiv 1\pmod 4$$
$$x\equiv 7\pmod {25}$$

And finally,

$$37^{45}\equiv 57\pmod {100}$$

Comment: Why did you use negative numbers?

Comment: I first used negative numbers to evaluate $11^{11} \pmod {25}$. It is easy to see that $11^2=121\equiv 21 \pmod {25}. Now since $21$ is large, it is convineient to use $-4$ as a negative remainder means $4$ less than a multilple of $5$. you could have used $21$ or you could have breaken up $11^{11}$ in a different way, maybe using cubes.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially we need $37^{45}\pmod{100}$

$$(40-3)^2\equiv3^2-2(3)40\equiv70-1\pmod{100}$$

$$37^{2n+1}=37(37^2)^n$$

$$\equiv37(70-1)^n$$

$$\equiv37(-1)^n(1-\binom n170^1)\pmod{100}$$

Here $n=22$

So, $$\binom n170^1=22\cdot70\equiv40\pmod{100}$$

Comment: I think you need to check you first line, where you deduced that $37^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {100}$

Comment: @h-squared, thanks